# solr: QueryResponse customization

Tags: solr, solrj

I inserted many tables into solr. Now im searching for words across all fields[Globally]. Also im searching for words within sentence, ex: PROJECT_DESC:My project has some big phrases.
Now field name is PROJECT_DESC & its value is My project has some big phrases. I will search for 'phr*' through java, it will give whole doc object. My question is: Is there any way QueryResponse also returns matched word i.e., phrases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) and add the PROJECT_DESC field to search on it.
Then in your result you'll have a highlighting tag and you can find the exact match word